# Replacing some characters in the previous command

Tags: command-line, bash, special-characters

Sometimes, being rushed, it is possible to type some characters wrong in a command-line. If the command is long, the mistake correction may be cumbersome (using arrow keys). So the problem is: how can I replace characters typed wrong in the previous command as quickly as possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One character or more can be replaced with zero, one or more characters as follow:

```
$ some-wrong-long-command
$ ^wrong^correct^
some-correct-long-command
```

This quick substitution repeat the last command-line from terminal, replacing `wrong` string with `correct` string.

Examles:

[image]

Comment: Nice, but I actually prefer the arrow keys. And ctrl+arrow and begin/end keys (to jump words or go to start/end of the line directly). Your string replacement solution is nice, but it's easy to make mistakes. Now for `cd`, that's harmless, but `rm` could be a desaster. Besides, `cd` doesn't usually have typos as you'd use tab completion anyway.

Comment: @frostschutz I used `cd` just for example; it could be anything. And, personally, I don't think  that I can be passible by a typing mistake if I made another mistake 1 second ago

Comment: +1. the `^bad^good` form only replaces the first one. for global replace in the previous command use `!!:gs/bad/good`

Comment: To repeat the substitution, use `:&`, i.e. `^bad^good^:&` will change `bad bad bad` to `good good bad`.  You can keep stacking `:&` but after two probably you should use `:gs` as suggested.

Comment: You can also explore the vi mode in bash. This seems to make these things easier.